# Pass the url view in the forms label. DJango

Tags: django, forms

How to correctly pass the view name in 'label'.  My form looks like that.

```
class DocumentationForm(forms.Form):
    documentation = forms.BooleanField(label='I accept the terms and <a href="{%s}">conditions</a>.' %('app:documentation'),
                                       initial=False)

    def clean_website_rules(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['documentation']
        if not data:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please accept the terms and privacy policy.")
        else:
            return data
```

When I click on the link, something like that is created. `host:name/data_1/data_2/data_3/documentation/`

But how to receive:

```
host:name/documentation/
```

If I used this in the template, the correct name would look like this `{% url 'app:documentation' %}`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `reverse` or `reverse_lazy`.

```
documentation = forms.BooleanField(
    label='I accept the terms and <a href="{%s}">conditions</a>.' % reverse_lazy('app:documentation'),
    initial=False
)
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse).

Comment: Why in my situation raises this error? 'The included URLconf 'app_rama.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.' Do I loss any imports? I added 'from django.urls import reverse_lazy' . My patterns are ofcourse in the 'app:urls' why is it in wrong answer 'app_rama.urls'. I use it in the form you write 'reverse_lazy('app:documentation')'.